# migrating spring security from 3.2.7.RELEASE to 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-security

just migrated from 3.2.7 to 4.0.1 and having this issue ,

my config :

```
http .anonymous().disable() .authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/*Service/**") .hasIpAddress(subnetMask)
```

> 3.2.7 : response 200
>
> 4.0.1 : AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

turns out the default role prefix is added to the ConfigAttribute ,

```
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

@Inject Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource ms;

ms.setDefaultRolePrefix("R_");`
```